# Meteor Cordova error running android

Tags: java, android, cordova, meteor

When I tried to use Meteor-cordova to run an app with android, I get this error:

> To add the android platform, please install a JDK. Here are some directions: http://openjdk.java.net/install/
>   Failed to install android_bundle: Failed to run bash

I already have  installed JDK but the error still there. Also I tried to install Android SDK manually, but it doesn't work.

Does someone know why this happened and how to fix it?

Comment: this error is thrown when `javac` is not in the path

Comment: This is not a meteorjs, error. This error is due to path of java,javac and jre not found in $path variable. check this this link [link] (http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide) to learn more about how to add path.

Answer (score 0):

On Oracle Linux 6

I had this error after

yum install java-1.7.0-openjdk

solution was to install the development package

yum install java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel

then meteor add-package android  worked

Comment: running in a 64-bit environment??? you might also find this helpful http://www.ossmentor.com/2013/08/error-executing-aapt-within-eclipse.html

Answer (score 0):

you should install jdk to be able to compile cordova apps. On ubuntu or ubuntu based distros you can do that so:
`sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk`